# Cabal sandbox is using a global dependency. Could not resolve

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to add `timerep` onto an existing application. I can't get it to resolve my dependencies. It looks like it is using the globally installed version of `time == 1.4.2`, when `>= 1.5` would be ideal for my application.

How can I get cabal to use time 1.5? I've poked through unix, tls, process, timerep, and they all seem like they would work fine if it would just use `time >= 1.5`.

Here's the error:

```
serials> cabal install --only-dependencies
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: serials-0.1.0.2 (user goal)
trying: mandrill-0.2.2.0 (dependency of serials-0.1.0.2)
trying: http-client-tls-0.2.2 (dependency of mandrill-0.2.2.0)
trying: tls-1.2.17 (dependency of http-client-tls-0.2.2)
trying: x509-validation-1.5.2 (dependency of tls-1.2.17)
trying: process-1.2.0.0/installed-487... (dependency of x509-validation-1.5.2)
next goal: unix (dependency of process-1.2.0.0/installed-487...)
rejecting: unix-2.7.0.1/installed-299... (conflict: unix =>
time==1.4.2/installed-bf9..., serials => time>=1.5)
rejecting: unix-2.7.1.0, 2.7.0.1, 2.7.0.0, 2.6.0.1, 2.6.0.0, 2.5.1.1, 2.5.1.0,
2.5.0.0, 2.4.2.0, 2.4.1.0, 2.4.0.2, 2.4.0.1, 2.4.0.0, 2.3.2.0, 2.3.1.0,
2.3.0.0, 2.2.0.0, 2.0 (conflict: process => unix==2.7.0.1/installed-299...)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

---

[Cabal file](https://github.com/seanhess/serials/blob/master/cabal.config):

```
-- Initial serials.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                serials
version:             0.1.0.2
synopsis:            serials
description:         serials
license:             MIT
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Sean Hess
maintainer:          Sean Hess
-- copyright:
category:            Web Scraper
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10
Source-repository head
  type:       git
  location:   git@github.com:seanhess/serials.git

executable serials
  main-is:             Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:      server
  ghc-options:         -fcontext-stack=36
  -- other-modules:
  -- other-extensions:
  default-language:     Haskell2010
  build-depends:
    base >=4.7 && <5,
    tagsoup,
    text,
    scalpel,
    containers,
    network-uri,
    monad-loops,
    wreq,
    lens,
    bytestring,
    parsec,
    utf8-string,
    tagsoup,
    xml,
    feed,
    regex-pcre,
    aeson,
    network,
    wai,
    wai-extra,
    wai-cors,
    wai-middleware-static,
    warp,
    servant-server >= 0.4,
    rethinkdb >= 1.16,
    transformers,
    either,
    unordered-containers,
    mtl,
    http-types,
    safe,
    hashable,
    resource-pool,
    time >= 1.5,
    pooled-io,
    shelly,
    string-conversions,
    bcrypt,
    random,
    jwt,
    cookie,
    entropy,
    mandrill == 0.2.2.0,
    email-validate,
    blaze-markup,
    blaze-html,
    iso8601-time,
    scotty == 0.10.0,
    timerep >= 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult for cabal-install to produce a complete description of the mutual incompatibilities of an installation problem. It instead decides to print the first path to failure.

However, it prints `Dependency tree exhaustively searched.` which indicates that there actually is no solution to the given problem.

One thing that often helps is to look at the choices cabal-install has made, find one that seems suboptimal, and then add an explicit constraint to change that. This may result in a better error message.

Let's try [note that I'm not sure if I have exactly the same package DB as you have, so it may produce different results on your system].

You had (modulo hashes of installed packages):

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: serials-0.1.0.2 (user goal)
trying: mandrill-0.2.2.0 (dependency of serials-0.1.0.2)
trying: http-client-tls-0.2.2 (dependency of mandrill-0.2.2.0)
trying: tls-1.2.17 (dependency of http-client-tls-0.2.2)
trying: x509-validation-1.5.2 (dependency of tls-1.2.17)
trying: process-1.2.0.0/installed-06c... (dependency of x509-validation-1.5.2)
next goal: unix (dependency of process-1.2.0.0/installed-06c...)
rejecting: unix-2.7.0.1/installed-f86... (conflict: unix =>
time==1.4.2/installed-9b3..., serials => time>=1.5)
rejecting: unix-2.7.1.0, 2.7.0.1, 2.7.0.0, 2.6.0.1, 2.6.0.0, 2.5.1.1, 2.5.1.0,
2.5.0.0, 2.4.2.0, 2.4.1.0, 2.4.0.2, 2.4.0.1, 2.4.0.0, 2.3.2.0, 2.3.1.0,
2.3.0.0, 2.2.0.0, 2.0 (conflict: process => unix==2.7.0.1/installed-f86...)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Looking through this, the error occurs with `unix`, which is a dependency of `process`. So the installed instance of `process` being chosen leads to trouble. So what if we disallow choosing that instance of `process`?

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies --constraint="process source"
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: serials-0.1.0.2 (user goal)
next goal: time (dependency of serials-0.1.0.2)
rejecting: time-1.4.2/installed-9b3... (conflict: serials => time>=1.5)
trying: time-1.5.0.1
next goal: rethinkdb (dependency of serials-0.1.0.2)
rejecting: rethinkdb-1.16.0.0 (conflict: time==1.5.0.1, rethinkdb =>
time==1.4.*)
rejecting: rethinkdb-1.15.2.1, 1.15.2.0, 1.15.1.0, 1.15.0.0, 1.8.0.5, 1.8.0.4,
1.8.0.3, 1.8.0.2, 1.8.0.1, 1.8.0.0, 0.1.0.0 (conflict: serials =>
rethinkdb>=1.16)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Aha! So `rethinkdb`, which is a direct dependency of `serials`, has an explicit dependency on `time == 1.4.*`. This is in direct conflict with the dependency of `serials` on `time >= 1.5`.

This is not easy to fix. You either need to make `rethinkdb` work with the newer `time` library, or `serials` with the older.

We enter the realm of speculation now: It is possible, but not guaranteed, that `rethinkdb` actually works with a newer version of `time`. We can try to instruct cabal-install to consider such install plans:

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies --allow-newer=time
```

This actually yields an install plan on my machine. I have not tried building it, and I don't know whether it works. But it may be worth a try.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Thank you for walking me through how you figured it out. What does `source` mean in the constraint?

Comment: It means that installed instances are excluded.